# Securing a web app against authorization API without revealing credentials

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, credentials, hashicorp-vault

I have a web app MyWebApp.

And two APIs: MyAuthAPI and MyServiceAPI, both RESTful NodeJS. MyAuthAPI uses HashiCorp Vault as a token store with OAuth2.

MyServiceAPI has CRUD operations available to authenticated clients.

There is no human login required (or desired) on MyWebApp. Any human can access MyWebApp through a browser and run the service.

At present, this is the (very insecure) flow:
MyWebApp sends clientid and clientsecret to MyAuthAPI to retrieve token. This token is then used for communicating with MyServiceAPI.

The obvious downside is that anyone can capture the clientid and clientsecret by simply looking in developer tools in a web browser. They could then use those to authenticate with MyAuthAPI, generate their own token, and make calls to MyServiceAPI without MyWebApp being involved.

So how do I best secure the entire application so that MyWebApp is safely and robustly authenticated without revealing the credentials?

Thanks.

ETA:
I want to be able to authenticate MyWebApp with MyAuthAPI and then use the generated token to connect to MyServiceAPI. But I don't want it to be possible that anyone can intercept those credentials - currently they can be see in the request header as "Authorization: Basic "

The MyServiceAPI endpoints must be secured so that only authenticated clients are able to access them. But when that client (MyWebApp) is a public website, how do I authenticate without making the credentials visible?

ETA2:

```
https://mywebapp.com is MyWebApp which is a React application.
https://myauthapi.com hosts MyAuthAPI
https://myserviceapi.com hosts MyServiceAPI
```

When I load mywebapp.com in a web browser, it authenticates with myauthapi.com/oauth/token to get a token. At present it does this by sending the creds in the header Authorization: Basic

The token that is returned is then saved.
The web application then tries to get the data from an endpoint on MyServiceApi using this token:
Authorization: Bearer

```
GET https://myserviceapi.com/objects
or POST myserviceapi.com/objects
or GET myserviceapi.com/objects/objectid
or DELETE myserviceapi.com/objects/objectid
```

MyServiceAPI verifies the token with MyAuthAPI, but that isn't public-facing, so there's no issue there.

The issue is that, as you can see from the attached screenshot of the Developer Tools console in Chrome, anyone using the web application can see the Authorization header containing the credentials, and could then use these credentials to programatically gain access to the auth API to generate a token which can then be used on the service API endpoints.
I want to restrict all access to the API servers to only come from specific applications, such as MyWebApp, on mywebapp.com.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JoyoWaseem I added some more info. Does that make it any clearer?

Comment: MyServiceAPI is not a service in MyWebApp ? if it is, what do you mean by : "...and make calls to MyServiceAPI without MyWebApp being involved"? 

didn't you mean "and make calls to MyServiceAPI without **MyAuthAPI** being involved"?

Comment: In short You can't secure your API key in a client-side app ! You can use body as @OhadR said. Bit of advice use Nginx as proxy server for your node RestApi then configure Nginx in a way so it can receive request from domains that you wish to allow.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think this question could better be asked in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Second, where MyWebApp is deployed? How it is being used? If it works with https, then the body is encrypted, and when you send the clientId and clientSecret, you should send it in the body, so users will not be able to see them.

Answer (score 1):

Client Credentials Grant should only be used by confidential Clients. Thats because you can't hide the client_secret on non confidential Clients. Your frontend seems to be a non confidential Client.

Normally you should use the Authorization Code Grant with PKCE. But you would need users to authenticate themselves for that.

Answer (score 0):

Feels like you need an architecture design based on standard flows, since OAuth should work like this:

- Web app signs user in via an Authorization Server, using Authorization Code Flow (PKCE)
- Web app gets tokens from the Authorization Server
- Web app calls API with an access token
- API validates token using data from the Authorization Server
- API then trusts claims in the access token and uses them for authorization

See my [Initial HTTP Messages](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/) blog post for an example of how this looks.